# Can't load installed packages with “no title available” message in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I installed Rstudio in our lab's server, and run as a non-root user. I usually installed R packages in a directory created by my self and I have the privilege to read and write. However, I found packages installed previously in that directory can no longer be used, and there are error messages which say "** No title available **".

I found there is no more DESCRIPTION file in the directory of some installed packages. I don't what happened to them:

```
$ ls
Meta  R  help  libs
```

should be something like:

```
$ ls
DESCRIPTION  INDEX  LICENSE  Meta  NAMESPACE  NEWS.md  R  doc  help  html  libs
```

I have no idea about what to do now and I don't want to install so many packages again.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-14 cowplot_0.9.3 ggplot2_3.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17       lattice_0.20-35    withr_2.1.2        grid_3.5.0         plyr_1.8.4        
 [6] gtable_0.2.0       scales_0.5.0       pillar_1.2.3       rlang_0.2.1        lazyeval_0.2.1    
[11] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tools_3.5.0        munsell_0.5.0      yaml_2.2.0         compiler_3.5.0    
[16] colorspace_1.3-2   BiocManager_1.30.4 knitr_1.20         tibble_1.4.2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from far away it is hard to say what happend without any further information. My assumption is that there was an Update of the R-Version.

Comment: @floe Thanks, it's possible. My rsession also collapsed for unknown reason.